# Make Wine app the default opener

Tags: mac, wine

I have Notepad which I open with "Wine".
I want to do that when I want to open file .txt, it will be opened by Wine Notepad.

How can I do that?

Comment: only wondering why you want opening Windows Notepad for the text files...

Comment: Because it's special notepad and I must it :/

Comment: Good question, oh by the way, I hate to say it but ..... **This is madness!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: I think [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) may help with this. I haven't actually tried it yet, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You will need:

- make a custom `launcher/wrapper` for the notepad, e.g. `WineNotepad.app`
- and in CMD-I you must change the default application for .txt files to the new launcher - and "change all"

how to create the custom launcher [is here](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX/FAQs#head-f1c814a8ca500350af40d817fc3b7ffc87fd3911)

Comment: thanks for this answer ^__^ but it's pretty hard.. maybe you have something more easy?

Comment: yes. Install Parallels and the the launcher/wrapper will be created auto-magically... ;)

Comment: I stuck here: --edit wineLocation if your wine install is not the default location<br />
        set wineLocation to "/usr/local/bin" What the means "wine install"? its at Applications, no? ohh ye and more question: can i get your skype/messenger? :)

Comment: i'm not an wine user, so don't know what wine you got and where it is installed. Maybe some real wine user will give a better advice. ;)

Comment: About Parallels: IF i want it, I need to download all window system and my computer will be more slower, thats right?

Comment: you will need windows - yes. Windows will take some place on your HDD. When you will run parallels will consume memory a processor time. The overhead is approx. 5% (or less), in usual applications - so your windows app will run 5% slower as native.

Comment: Now.. I need windows 7 :P you know where I can download?

Comment: @Daniel You'll need to buy Windows for use in Parallels. Don't steal it.